# How to create a public directory/folder on a plesk windows server?

Tags: https, plesk, file-sharing

I'm trying to create a public accessible directory on my plesk server, but I haven't had any luck so far.
There used to be a easy feature for that "File Sharing" (on the plesk server), but its deprived since a few years.
They recommend to use one of the extension to fix the missing function, but none of the extension works on a windows server.

I would like to share a directory on my domain, e.g. https://myurl.com/XYZ/picures where everyone can see and acess all the files stored within this folder.

Thanks for trying to help!

looked for a extension that works with windows server